# Token Authenticatable module in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, token

I'm starting using Devise in my Rails app, but the `Token Authenticatable`: *signs in a user based on an authentication token (also known as "single access token")* module puzzles me.

Is the user authenticated only for his current session? If he uses now the URL containing the token, can he re-use it at a later tine and still have access, or does he get a *single* access?

Can multiple users be authenticated at the same time, using the same token?

*I have searched extensively for a working example; please forgive me if this is explained elsewhere. 
Any pointers would be more than welcomed. Thanks for your help.*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The short answer is: it's up to you.

> This module only provides a few
>   helpers to help you manage the token,
>   but it is up to you to choose how to
>   use it. For example, if you want to
>   have a new token every time the user
>   saves his account, you can do the
>   following:
>
> ```
> before_save :reset_authentication_token
> ```
>
> On the other hand, if you want to
>   generate token unless one exists, you
>   should use instead:
>
> ```
> before_save :ensure_authentication_token
> ```
>
> If you want to delete the token after
>   it is used, you can do so in the
>   after_token_authentication callback.

See the documentation for this model at http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/TokenAuthenticatable.

Comment: I also use devise and tokens and it works great for almost every action in my API but if the user needs to change data in the user object for example name or email he needs to login. In all other parts it works with just the token. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Jonathan - is that happening because you're reseting the authentication token any time the user is saved, thereby invalidating your currently stored token?